# Harnessed .. to the task of

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about the verb "***harness***".  According to definitions of many dictionaries, including definition 2 for the verb "***harness***" in this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/harness), "***harness***" should be used according to pattern "*harness something to do something*".  But, then I saw this in some [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=4XMSl-aFk1YC&pg=PA336&lpg=PA336&dq=%22harnessed+them+to+the+task+of+forging+it%22&source=bl&ots=aQFFF8Cfu5&sig=4mlhCecvsrSIKIDg90sOxgETZ9Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj644Hu2fnOAhUUH2MKHf9cBAMQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22harnessed%20them%20to%20the%20task%20of%20forging%20it%22&f=false):

> He had an intuitive feel for the tribal and ethnic dynamics, but instead of exploiting them to tear the nation apart, he ***harnessed them to the task of forging it***.

, which does not use the pattern "**harness** *something to do something*"  . So, is the example in the book wrong?

Comment: I was not successful in finding this pattern: "harness something **to do** something", but I found this pattern: "harness something to something".

Comment: Your dictionary does not tell you that _harness_ **must** be used **only** in the "pattern" _harness something to do something._ Your dictionary tells you that the verb **can** be used in that way. It is only one example. in the same sense that a horse is _harnessed_ to a plow, the _tribal and ethnic dynamics_ here are _harnessed_ to the task.